# Is this correct: "I didn't skip gym for no reason"

Tags: grammar, double-negation

I was having a conversation with my coworkers, and we just can't seem to agree on what is the grammatically correct way to say this.

In the context of the conversation, he was trying to express that he skipped his gym session in order to attend a club meeting.

I think the correct way to say this would be "I skipped gym for a reason." instead of "I didn't skip gym for no reason." 
For one, his statement actually means he "worked out" for "no reason", but you can hardly tell what it's saying with the double negatives in there.

Everyone else in the office seems to disagree with me though, and I think I'm going crazy. Is that actually proper English?

Comment: what was the co-worker *actually* meaning?

Comment: Both "I didn't skip gym for no reason" and "I skipped gym for a reason" mean the same thing - when used properly. Double negatives are normally used when one wants to emphasize something, precisely because they can easily be misunderstood by the inattentive listener.

Comment: "I didn't skip gym for nothing" which means that there was a reason *why* I skipped my gym session.

Comment: The double negative could use some framework to make more sense of it: "You skipped gym for no reason?" "I didn't skip gym for no reason." Usually when you startle someone with "I didn't skip gym for no reason," you follow up with more detail: "I had my own reasons, don't worry."

Comment: Note that ambiguity also attaches to the sentence "I didn't skip gym for any reason"—which may mean either "I didn't skip gym—and there was no reason sufficient to have made me skip it" or "I skipped gym—but not for a particular reason." In contrast, "I didn't skip gym for no reason" may mean either "I didn't skip gym —and there was no reason sufficient to have made me skip it—and I'm using a double negative to express this idea" or "I did skip gym—and I had one or more particular reasons for doing so."

Comment: "I didn't skip gym without a [good] reason [for doing so]' is more idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I'd say "I didn't skip gym for no reason” is idiomatic. "I didn't skip gym without a [good] reason" is attempting to avoid idiomatic expression and be more neutral English.

Comment: @developerwjk Do you know what the primary (and hence default) sense of 'idiomatic' is? It's not 'being, like, of or relating to an idiom'. It's 'being a preferred usage of a natural speaker'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you referring to a definition like "using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker"? I think "I didn't skip gym for no reason” is more natural to many native speakers, and "I didn't skip gym without a [good] reason" would seem quite academic to them, hence a way of avoiding being idiomatic.

Comment: Obviously, your comment ' "I didn't skip gym without a [good] reason" is attempting to avoid idiomatic expression and be more **neutral** English.' is using 'idiomatic' in the other valid sense. I can't find many examples of 'didn't V for no reason' on the internet, but then I didn't find many of 'didn't V without a good reason'. Drawing on my (long) experience, the former sounds marked or quirky (and see Yosef Bakin's comment) or even clunky.

Comment: 'Idiom' means "understood despite literal interpretation", while 'idiomatic' means "understood by a certain group".  Idiomatic statements may be literal, but idioms never are.  'Idiomatic' is not a well behaved word.

Answer (score 2):

The use of a double negative, in a way, makes me think that the speaker felt accused of skipping for no reason.  Saying, "I didn't skip gym for no reason." emphasizes that more than, "I had a good reason for skipping gym." It seems like understandable idiomatic English to me.